# Why can't I update value of Unity Text in my function?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am trying to display error messages according to what type of error occurs. For that, I have a public variable "errorMessage" which is attached to UI Text in the inspector. I am able to change the text value in start function but can't seem to change that value in GetErrorMessage function. Following is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Auth;
using System;


public class LoginController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField email, password; 
    public Screen nextScreen;
    public Text errorMessage;

    void Start()
    {
        password.inputType = InputField.InputType.Password;
        errorMessage.text = "This is error"; //this works
    }


    public void Login()
    {
        //login code which calls GetErrorMessage(error)
    }
    void GetErrorMessage(string error)
    {
        print("error function called");
        print(error);
        print(errorMessage.text); //works till here
        errorMessage.text = error; //doesn't work from here. Seems like it stops functioning.
        print(error); //and this never gets printed
    }
}
```

[Inspector: Error Message is attached to my UI text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGjoI.png)

Comment: and there are no error messages??? any chance you are doing this in a thread?

Comment: apply error messages on update, you can use a bool on your GetErrorMessage method  to flag update and a condition for this bool in Update to apply the change.

Answer (score 1):

Your function runs until the end, unless you're getting a NullReferenceException (which is the only possible exception you can get from that method).

What I believe is happening is that in your Console panel , you have the "Collapse" option ticked, so the message stacks instead.

[image]

If you want to make sure it runs, in your last line of GetErrorMessage() print "Error function exits" instead.

Comment: I checked there was no NullReferenceException. But my problem is fixed now, thanks to @joreldraw.